# Average and Standard Deviation for every hour of measurements

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, standard-deviation, array-formulas

I have an Excel file with time logs and measurement taken at each time, the list is keeping logs for several days. I want to calculate the average and the standard deviation of the measurements for every hour.

My problem is that the amount of measurements taken each hour is different, so I can't even start.

The list looks like this:

```
Time            measurement
28/8/2013 16:17 3831
28/8/2013 16:36 3668
28/8/2013 16:36 3685
28/8/2013 16:36 3676
28/8/2013 17:13 3671
28/8/2013 17:36 3669
28/8/2013 17:36 3664
28/8/2013 18:36 3654
28/8/2013 18:36 3661
```

And I need output like this:

```
  Hour             Average      Stdv
28/08/2013 16:00    3715    77.64448897
28/08/2013 17:00    3668    3.605551275
28/08/2013 18:00    3657.5  4.949747468
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) can readily accomplish the first task.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B$2:B$10, A$2:A$10, ">="&D3, A$2:A$10, "<"&D3+TIME(1, 0, 0))
```

You will need an *array formula* for the conditions on a [STDEV.S function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-S-function-7D69CF97-0C1F-4ACF-BE27-F3E83904CC23) for the second.

```
=STDEV.S(IF(A$2:A$10>=D3, IF(A$2:A$10<D3+TIME(1, 0, 0), B$2:B$10)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.
Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum.

[image]

If your datetimes in column A are sorted in an ascending order, this standard formula should work.

```
=STDEV.S(INDEX(B:B, IFERROR(MATCH(D3-TIME(0, 0, 1), A:A)+1,2)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D3+TIME(0, 59, 59), A:A)))
```

While that looks more complex, it parses the range of values from column B down to the matching values from column A using an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair. This should greatly reduce the calculations on a long list of datetimes. This is NOT an array formula and does NOT require Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it did work ! but the thing is that I have lots of data to sort, so I hope it will handle the Standard Deviation calculations well :)

Answer (score 1):

Pivot the data with `Time` for ROWS and `measurement` in VALUES twice, once as Average and once as StdDev. Group your rows with selecting Years, Months, Days and Hours.

Comment: Thanks, butI didn't understand exactly what you mean